# Sort a javascript array by asc value after json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, sorting

I'm writing to you today because I have an issue with sorting my javascript array, I show you ;

In my php script, I json_encode my data.

```
$data[$value->id_fiche] = $nom . $prenom . $societe;
```

Here is an example of what appears when I die(var_dump($data)), before the json_encode($data) :

```
    array(6) {
  [733]=>
  string(24) "ABAD Juan [123 MATIERES]"
  [734]=>
  string(13) "Abassi Denise"
  [735]=>
  string(13) "ABBAS Ibtisem"
  [736]=>
  string(14) "ABEYTUA Alvaro"
    }
    }
```

In my js file, I must add options in my select thanks to `$.each(data, function (i, item)`

But options aren't added in the right order, the $.each function orders by $value->id_fiche.

How can I sort my data.contact by values instead of keys before my $.each function ?

EDIT : in other ways, is it possible for the jquery function $.each to work in values order instead of keys order?

Thank you !

Comment: can post the resulting json, or parts of it?

Comment: [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)($data['contact'])

Comment: I did with the die(var_dump) function , only a part because there is 5944 arrays

Comment: I must sort it in the javascript file, its already in the right order in my php script thanks to my sql request.

Comment: @NolweenLopez: Then you should make sure it's encoded in the JSON in the right order. Use an array.

Comment: In JavaScript, only arrays are ordered, objects are not.  If you want a specific order, you need to make sure your JSON is outputting an array.  You may need to use `array_values()` to re-index your array (which will make you lose your keys) after using `sort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to work like that in my php script code :

```
 $data[$nom . $prenom . $value->id_fiche] = $nom . $prenom . $societe;
```

Its works like it, I could even just set  `$data[$nom]= $nom . $prenom . $societe;` but I need the ID later, and having to same name is possible.

I wish I could help someone later with it :)